# Persian word in html page title

Tags: tags, title

I have a problem with a persian word in html page title.

Please see this :

[image: image1]

And this :

[image: image2]

It is not showing correct. How can I solve this?

Comment: That's an RTL issue.  Good luck.  Try http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

Allways properly set the encoding (e.g. in the html document or via headers):

**Examples using UTF-8:**

*In HTML:*

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
...
```

*In PHP:*

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Also check out Right to Left (RTL): [Creating HTML Pages in Arabic, Hebrew and Other Right-to-left Scripts](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/bidi-xhtml/)

In case you use PHP to serve the page, check out these resources:

- [Strategy for supporting unicode & multi language in PHP5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085093/2493918)
- [Storing and displaying unicode string (हिन्दी) using PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1198701/2493918)
- [what is the best method to build "multilingual" script in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457586/2493918)

Comment: this solution solved my problem. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

also Farsi language in HTML document

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp">and other languages</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[and other languages](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp)